# How can I get file object properties with a button click?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I currently have a form with a file input that I am needing to get the value of on a button click. I am able to get the information using the @change prop that I currently have attached, but I am needing it on a button click on the form.

```
<v-card>
  <v-card-title>
    <h2>New File Submission</h2>
  </v-card-title>
  <v-card-text>
    <v-form v-model='valid' ref='form' lazy-validation>
      <v-container>
        <!-- file input -->
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols='12' md='12'>
            <v-file-input
              v-model='files'
              ref='files'
              color='success'
              counter
              label='File input'
              accept='.csv'
              placeholder='Select your files'
              prepend-icon='mdi-paperclip'
              outlined
              :rules='fileRules'
              :show-size='1000'
              @change='fileSelected($event)'
            >
              <template v-slot:selection='{ index, text }'>
                <v-chip v-if='index < 2' color='success' dark label small>{{ text }}</v-chip>

                <span
                  v-else-if='index === 2'
                  class='overline grey--text text--darken-3 mx-2'
                >+{{ files.length - 2 }} File(s)</span>
              </template>
            </v-file-input>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>

      <v-btn :disabled='!valid' text class='success mx-0 mt-3' @click='submitFile'>Submit File</v-btn>
      <v-btn text class='error mx-0 ml-3 mt-3' @click='reset'>Reset Form</v-btn>
    </v-form>
  </v-card-text>
</v-card>
```

I have put a reference on the file input and tried to access it that way through my submit function as shown in the code below.

```
data() {
    return {
      files: [],
      fileRules: [v => !v || v.size < 2000000 || 'A file is required'],
    };
  }

submitFile() {
      if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
        const file = this.$refs.files.file
        console.log(file)
      }
    }
```

The console logs "undefined" with the code above. If I do `const file = this.$refs.files.file[0]` I get "Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined""

Any help would be appreciated, I have been trying to look everywhere for a solution but can't seem to find one. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need that if you set `v-model` for your data `files`?

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov that seems to be the only thing I did not try. I removed that and just referenced it as `const file = this.files` from the `v-model`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by removing the `ref = 'files'` and just referencing it off the `v-model` with `const file = this.files`. Guess I was defeating myself over and over again. Thanks to Daniyal for the helpful question in the comments.